# Why is there a command-1 on top of my terminal window?

Tags: terminal

I had always noticed this on my Mac and was curious as to why it is there.  What does it mean?

[image: terminal]

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts (like here) and you should be able to accept one of the answers as well if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in the profile settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ⌘-symbol is the traditional symbol for the cmd-key on your keyboard. Try opening multiple terminal windows and pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The Command-1 is shown as an option in:

Terminal Preferences -> Profiles -> (The Profile you are using) -> Window -> ***Command Key***.

[image]

(My preferred profile is Novel, your's may be Basic or other.)

It's simply a shortcut to bringing that window to the forefront, if you have multiple windows open.

If you click on the Windows menu, you will see each window has it's own shortcut there too, even if you disable the option in the Preferences/Profile window.

[image]